# Does this integral converges?!

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

My question concerns the convergence of the following integral

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{x\sin(mx)+\cos(mx)}{x^2(x^2+1)}dx $$

I try to solve it by using the Residue Theory to evaluate the integral

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{\exp{imx}}{x^2(x-i)}dx=2\pi i(1-m-e^{-m}) $$

Then to find my result, I used the fact that

$$ \frac{x\sin(mx)+\cos(mx)}{x^2(x^2+1)}=Im\{\frac{\exp{imx}}{x^2(x-i)}\} $$

Finally, I got

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{x\sin(mx)+\cos(mx)}{x^2(x^2+1)}dx = 2\pi(1-m-e^{-m}) $$

But a friend without giving proofs or more details told me that this calculus can't be true since the integral is divergent. So, is that true that this integral does not converge?

Comment: It diverges.  Consider it near $x=0$.

Comment: Note that the residue theorem generally gives you the principal value of an integral irrespective of whether the integral actually converges.

Comment: From your comments I conclude that this integral diverges but, if I'm supposed to calculate this integral should I say "this integral diverges so it has no solution" or should I give the result which I found using residue theorem?

Comment: @çiçek I can't answer that without additional context. Most commonly if an integral diverges in the classical sense we either leave it at that or identify it with the principal value (usually with that caveat made explicit).

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Near zero, the integrand function is equivalent $(\sim) $ to $$\frac {1}{x^2} $$ 
and
$$\int_0\frac {dx}{x^2} $$
diverges.

Comment: Ok. I see that means that my integral diverges thank you